# iPhone edit XML in the memory on the run

Tags: iphone, xml, ios4

This question can be very simple but could not find the answer; I receive an XML from web service, I want to simply edit some nodes on it and send it back again, and I want to do this without writing the XML to disc, or converting whole XML into model objects and construct back again to an XML file. Just simply quickly edit XML on the run and send it back.

I can do this getting XML as a string from NSData and manipulate the string and then convert back NSData from that string again. But I don't think it is safe working on strings. I use GData XML as a parser but I guess the idea should be similar with other DOM parsers too.

p.s if you really think manipulating it as an NSString is harmless this can also be a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C XML manipulate as NSString is safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738598/objective-c-xml-manipulate-as-nsstring-is-safe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using `NSMutableDictonary` to manipulate partial data, as it allows you to access the data quickly by the key without need to parse the `NSString`.

Comment: tnx you know my app:) after I get the latest question from XML I will ask it then get the answer, put it back to XML and send. So I only need to parse/edit a very very small part of Xml.if I use nsmutabledictionary first I need to convert all XML into dictionary and vica verse?

Comment: Yes you would. Don't know what library you use, but it might have it already implemented. It will be very easy if it does. I my self don't use XML, only JSON hence, cant give you the exact code.

Comment: I use gdataxml, it has a gdataxmldocument object, should I directly work with it or still use nsdictionary?

Comment: You can work with GDataXMLDocument. Using this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) go to section: `Querying with XPath` to directly access the node data and use section: `Saving Back to XML` to save back the answer.

Comment: tnx I know that document, but it tells how to re-create an xml from elements. it does not tell if I can simply edit the current xmldocuments nodes without saving it to disc or parsing all of it, or I am missing it

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar edits converting from NSData and manipulating NSString and have not had any problems.  Try that approach before you resort to something more complex.

Comment: tnx do you know why it is said that to be not safe? for Null values or unicode problems maybe?